Enable creation of shared google drives through terraform
I can enable the google drive API with the terraform resource:
resource "google_project_service" "driveapi" {
  project = data.google_project.my_project.project_id
  service = "drive.googleapis.com"
}

however, I need to enable the following option, which can be found here in the console but I can't seem to enable it with terraform.

